# Can I edit multiple lines in compound path in Inkskape?

Tags: inkscape, path

In Figma, I can draw anything inside a single path:

[image: PCB icon in single not-closed path]

When exported to SVG, it consists of single `<path>` element.

```xml
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M3 12H10M11 12H13M5 4V0M8 1V3H11V1H8ZM9 6V9H12V6H9ZM4 6V9H5V6H4ZM15 4V13C15 14.1046 14.1046 15 13 15H3C1.89543 15 1 14.1046 1 13V4C1 2.89543 1.89543 2 3 2H13C14.1046 2 15 2.89543 15 4Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

But, when I try to edit like this in Inkscape, I get:

[image: two paths]

Is it possible to draw multiple not-closed lines in the same path in Inkscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Select all single paths and then combine them into a compound path by pressing
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or from the menu using *Path → Combine*.

(Later you may break them apart into separate paths by clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or from the menu using *Path → Break Apart*.)